# Pratical implementation of a Sibling Intractable Function

Tags: one-way-function

I have seen in several places the statement "k-SIFF can be constructed from any one-way function", but I cannot understand how this is realized in practice?

For instance, in
[Sibling Intractable Function Families
and Their Applications](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.49.7289&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Theorem 2.

Comment: can you provide a reference?

Comment: Added to the question.